# length property of functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

I don't understand what's going on here:

```
$ node
> var f = function() {};
> f['length'] = '11';
'11'
> f['length']
0
```

If you're not familiar with node, the code after `>` is what I typed, and the stuff not there are the returned values. So `f['length'] == 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Length property for functions is the number of arguments a function expects.

> Specifies the number of arguments expected by the function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Length

In your case, `f` doesn't take any paramater, so its length is `0`.

Comment: NB that all functions "take" any number of arguments. The `length` property is the number that the function *definition* contains.

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript, all functions have a [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Length) property.  It is the number of parameters that the function is defined with, and the property is read only.

Because you define no parameters (`function() {}`) the `length` property will always be `0`.

Comment: You probably meant *parameters* instead of *arguments*.

Answer (score 2):

The function object already have a property named `length`, and you can't change it.

The `length` property is the number of parameters there is in the function definition.

Example:

```
> var f = function(x) {};
> f.length
1
```